# Angular Validators.email allow null value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this Angular validator in my .ts file:

```
this.detailsForm = formBuilder.group(
            {

                email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email])]
            });
```

This works fine but when I apply email validator it also applies required validator. I want to allow null value as well. How would I do that?

Comment: @TimLiberty have you tried adding the validators dynamically and removed it if it's null ? That's another possiblity if you don't want to create your own custom validator

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because the `null`/empty value will not match against the expected shape (regexp).

[This](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts#L44) is the current regular expression used with the `Validators.email`:

```
const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*$/;

console.log(EMAIL_REGEXP.test('')); // false
console.log(EMAIL_REGEXP.test(null)); // false
console.log(EMAIL_REGEXP.test('a@a.com')); // true
```

For achieve what you want, you can either [build a custom validator](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html), that accepts this Regexp or a `null`/empty value, or what I would do if I had this requirement: [an async validator](https://kahlillechelt.com/asynchronous-validation-with-angular-reactive-forms-1a392971c062) that applies the `Validators.email` in the value if it has a `length` greater than 0.